# Is there other vulnerabilities than CVE of NVD

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, cve

I am aware that there is the CVE list published by the NVD. Are there any other important vulnerabilities lists that show vulnerabilities other than the NVDs?

Thx

Answer (score 4):

NVD covers a lot of vulnerabilities. Aside from those you also have:

- [Security Focus](http://www.securityfocus.com/) (bugtraq)
- [OSVDB](http://osvdb.org/)

They are often linked back to NVD CVE. Another interesting project to follow is [vFeed](https://github.com/toolswatch/vFeed) which provides cross linking between vendors and CVE vulnerabilities.

Note that this covers disclosed vulnerabilities. There are still a lot of vulnerabilities which might not get disclosed.

Comment: Yeah. I have seen those websites, but does it mean that, every known vulnerabilities is assigned to a CVE number today ? Or is there a few rebels that does not want to join the CVE numbering ?

Comment: @MathieuLeiv in an ideal world everyone would follow complete "full disclosure" etiquette this is unfortunatly not always the case; http://www.exploit-db.com/ is a good one to keep an eye on also as well as http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/

Comment: @MathieuLeiv If you check out exploit-db.com you will see that there are many vulns without CVEs. On the other hand, there are CVEs which correspond to multiple vulns...

Answer (score 0):

Currently the NVD only pulls from the Mitre CVE database, this will be changing, but for now if Mitre doesn't have an entry written up, it won't be in the NVD database. As for Mitre I know we (Red Hat) have assigned over a thousand CVEs that aren't in the Mitre Database, and even some of the CVEs Mitre assigns (e.g. on oss-security@ mailing list) aren't in the database after weeks/months, there's a huge backlog.

The good news is that for Open Source at least the DWF Project (Distributed Weakness Filing Project https://distributedweaknessfiling.org) will be addressing this and more.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complementing @Kurt's answer: Just as he has commented about [NIST] NVD (National Vulnerability Database) which is an U.S. government repository vulnerability database, another vulnerability database that is provided by the MITRE Corp itself is "CVEDetails.com".

Aside from MITRE Corporation and other government resources, there are several others that I not know every of them, but I will list the bests I know:

The first one is **IBM XForce Exchange**<sup>[1](https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/activity/list?filter=Vulnerabilities)</sup>. This is one of the place where you can track vulnerabilities before it is published on MITRE CVE. The other source that are not so rare to leak some receive information about whose vulnerability is SecList<sup>[2](https://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/)</sup> because some people that discover the software flaw chooses to send an e-mail to Seclist before announce at `cve.mitre.org` – it required a subscription to take the alert on your e-mail.

The another one is **CXSecurity**<sup>[3](https://securitytracker.com/)</sup> and **Seebug.org**<sup>[4](https://www.seebug.org/)</sup>, where can find some exploits or their write up which most of them are published before than **exploit-db.com**<sup>[5](https://www.exploit-db.com/)</sup>

The others sources are:

- SecurityFocus <sup>[6](https://securityfocus.com/)</sup>
- SecurityTracker<sup>[7](https://securitytracker.com/)</sup>
- PacketStorm<sup>[8](https://packetstormsecurity.com/)</sup>
- CERT Vulnerability Notes Database<sup>[9](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/bypublished)</sup>
- Japan Vulnerability Notes<sup>[10](http://jvn.jp/en/jp/)</sup>
- WordPress Vulnerability Database<sup>[11](https://wpvulndb.com/)</sup>
- Skybox Vulnerability Center<sup>[12](https://www.vulnerabilitycenter.com)</sup>

**Caution:** If you want to consume some information of these vulnerabilities databases mentioned above, I recommend you read their terms of conditions before use it to avoid some trouble.